# Easy binding of dbcontext with or without WCF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, xaml, dbcontext

**Dear Programmers,**

I have a question that I can't succeed to figure out, it is more related to how should I design the application, and until now I have always overcome this issue by writing a lot of code.

I have to design a silverlight application connected to a database, and I want to use a WCF service between these 2 for many reasons.

**If I use the WCF service I will loose the dbcontext structure which is very great when we want to use CollectionViewSource with related fields to bind the xaml controls.**

By example, lets say we have simple entities like that, generated from the edmx file: Resistor and ResistorCategories

```
public partial class ResistorCategories
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public ResistorCategories()
    {
        this.Name = "New";
        this.ResistorsSet = new HashSet<ResistorsSet>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ResistorsSet> ResistorsSet { get; set; }
}

public partial class ResistorsSet
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public ResistorsSet()
    {
        this.ResistorStockEntriesSet = new HashSet<ResistorStockEntriesSet>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Resistance { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> PowerRating { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Price { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Tolerance { get; set; }
    public string SupplierCode { get; set; }
    public string ManufacturerCode { get; set; }
    public int ResistorCategories_Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Suppliers_Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Manufacturers_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ResistorCategories ResistorCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual Suppliers Suppliers { get; set; }
    public virtual Manufacturers Manufacturers { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ResistorStockEntriesSet> ResistorStockEntriesSet { get; set; }
}
```

In the xaml, it is very easy to place 2 datagrid and see the list of resistors which belong to a categorie:

In the xaml:

Then I bind each datagrid to its corresponding CollectionViewSource:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource resistorCategoriesViewSource}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource resistorCategoriesResistorsViewSource}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

And in the code behind file, with lazyloading enabled:

```
 System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource resistorCategoriesViewSource =
               ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("resistorCategoriesViewSource")));
        //
        _context.ResistorCategoriesSet.Load();
        resistorCategoriesViewSource.Source = _context.ResistorCategoriesSet.Local;
```

So it can't be easier to display records with their related fields, but in this case the xaml client is querying the database directly and this is what I want to avoid with a WCF service, + adding some standardization and security.

With a WCF, first I have to generate the POCO objects with EF Power Tool, because it can't return IEnumerable by example because of its virtual property (even if I deactivate lazyloading and proxy).
Then I have to query and store in separated collections the POCO objects:
ObservableCollection && ObservableCollection

Then I bind each datagrid to its collection and monitor the selecteditem event to manually change the collection displayed in the datagrid for the resistors!

**So I guess there is a solution to use a WCF together with the simplicity of the dbcontext**! 
Please help me! Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of database you use? MySql, MsSQL, Postgres?

Comment: Hi, Thx for your message! I am actually using SQLEXPRESS for this project, usually I use MySql most of the time. I didn't find a solution yet, so I've decided to save time somewhere else: I have implemented the wcf data service so I almost don't have to write the wcf service and I can secure it using the integrated mechanism. I also can use it as datasource inside the xaml so I just drag and drop the forms and datagrids. Of course the last thing is about my post, I have to load and do the binding manually!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found a solution finally, it was worth searching even if the solution is easy: using **WCF Data Services**.

It's possible to query the database with all related entities and bind them in the xaml:

As example, consider an entity called ItemsCategory with a list of Items referring to it via a ItemCategory_Id field, and 2 others entities called ItemPrices and ItemImages referring Items via an Item_Id field:

- ItemsCategory
- - Item
- - - ItemPrices
- - - ItemImages

It's not perfect but it looks like that.

So then if you want to place a datagrid for the ItemsCategory and see the related Items in a second datagrid, and the related ItemPrices and ItemImages in a third and fourth datagrid in your xaml you defined it like that:

```
<navigation:Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="itemsCategoriesSetViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance SvcCatalogDatabase:ItemsCategories, CreateList=True}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="itemsCategoriesSetItemsSetViewSource" Source="{Binding Items, Source={StaticResource itemsCategoriesSetViewSource}}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="itemsCategoriesSetItemsSetItemsPricesSetViewSource" Source="{Binding ItemsPrices, Source={StaticResource itemsCategoriesSetItemsSetViewSource}}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="itemsCategoriesSetItemsSetItemsImagesSetViewSource" Source="{Binding ItemsImages, Source={StaticResource itemsCategoriesSetItemsSetViewSource}}"/>
</navigation:Page.Resources>
```

To load the entities you first define a collections like that:

```
public DataServiceCollection<ItemsCategories> ItemsCategoriesTracked { get; set; }
public CollectionViewSource ItemsCategories_CVSrc { get; set; }
```

And to query the database you just need to query ItemCategories with related entities:

```
ItemsCategories_CVSrc.Source = null;
ItemsCategoriesTracked.LoadAsync(this.SvcData.ItemsCategoriesSet.Expand("Items").Expand("Items/ItemsPrices,Items/ItemsImages"));
```

Of course you have defined a handler for the LoadCompleted event of the DataServiceCollection:

```
ItemsCategoriesTracked.LoadCompleted += new EventHandler<LoadCompletedEventArgs>((sender, e) => DataServiceCollection_LoadCompleted<ItemsCategories>(sender, e, ItemsCategories_CVSrc));

private void DataServiceCollection_LoadCompleted<T>(object sender, LoadCompletedEventArgs e, CollectionViewSource target)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            if ((sender as DataServiceCollection<T>).Continuation != null)
            {
                (sender as DataServiceCollection<T>).LoadNextPartialSetAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                target.Source = (sender as DataServiceCollection<T>);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}: An error has occured: {1}", typeof(T).Name, e.Error.Message));
        }
    }
```

And you've linked the CollectionViewSource to the one defined in the XAML:

```
ItemsCategories_CVSrc = (CollectionViewSource)this.Resources["itemsCategoriesSetViewSource"];
```

Voilà! Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

May be, you can implement your own "data provider", based on sample data provider: [Entity Framework 5 Sample Provider](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Entity-Framework-Sample-6a9801d0). But you need to "tunnel" and serialize data to send/receive throught wcf.

Answer (score 0):

Thx for your message, I think yes finally I will have to do sth like that, I am struggling trying to find an easy solution but I guess what I want to do is not possible.

Instead of trying to save time with the binding I should focus on saving time with the generation of data services. wcf data service is a good solution, I also tried codetrigger and I am actually trying to implement it with open ria services..... which seems to be buggy as hell!!

So I don't know honestly, I can do the data part using wcf data services, but I would like the silverlight app to retrieve also the name and roles on the currently authenticated user in the asp.net app in order to customized the UI. So I guess I have to use a 2nd wcf service just for that.

I am maybe dreaming but if possible I would like the silverlight app to receive a notification when a user logged in or out instead of querying the asp.net app all the times.

If I find a solution of course I will post it, because I think it is quite common when someone want to write a silverlight app.